# Numbers of different ways to distribute $m$ balls into $n$ boxes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So my question is this:

assuming I have $m$ balls how many ways there is to divide them into $n$ boxes (at least one ball for each box)?

For example if I have $7$ balls and I want to split them into $3$ boxes I can do:

$5, 1, 1 $

$4, 2, 1 $

$3, 3, 1 $

$3, 2, 2 $

meaning there is 4 ways (notice that $3,2,2$ is equal to $2,3,2$)

thanks in advanced !!

Comment: You want the number of partitions of $m$ into $n$ positive parts

Comment: Do you mean to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) ?

Comment: yes. but what I look for is the number of ways to partition m into n positive parts ? (example $m=8$ and $n = 4$ than the answer is $2$)

Comment: This is particular type of restricted partition. If $m=8$ and $n=4$ then the answer is $5$: $2+2+2+2$, $3+2+2+1$, $3+3+1+1$, $4+2+1+1$, $5+1+1+1$

Comment: Then how do I do that ?

Comment: See my answer for two ways.  Recursion is another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the number of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $m$ into $n$ positive parts.  See [OEIS A008284](http://oeis.org/A008284)

You can use the generating function and find the co-efficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of  $$\frac{x^n}{\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^n (1-x^j)}$$  or  [my Java applet](http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm)  with "Partitions of $m$" with "Exact number of terms: $n$"

Comment: first of all, thanks Henry !! my question for you is this : How do I use the function (and by the way, where is the $m$) because the way I understood that it is like that (for the above example $m=8,n=4$): $\frac{x^{4}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}$

Comment: Expand your generating function and you get something which starts  $x^4+x^5+ 2x^6+ 3x^7 +5x^8+ 6x^9+ 9x^{10}+ 11x^{11}+ 15x^{12}+ \cdots$.  You look at $5x^8$ to give you the answer $5$